# Python virtual environment not installing packages in correct directory (python)

Tags: python, module, pycharm, python-venv, pyvenv

I have set up a virtual environment correctly have activated it and when I do "which python" it tells me the correct directory, but when I do pip install in the venv it installs the package in the default directory of the mac and not in my venv. I have tried using pycharm and installing packages with that, but it happens the same thing.
Edit:
Following I will do a walkthru of my steps, first I did `python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`, then I did  `source env/bin/activate`, then I did `which python` and I got the intended directory, afterwards I did `pip3 install numpy` and I saw the installation process, then I did `pip list` and  numpy was not there, I checked the directory manually and it still was not there. I retried all the same thing with pycharm with the same results.

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv before installing the packages?

Comment: As you may imagine, probably they are doing the correct thing, but you are either executing things wrongly or a wrong assumption. But we cannot tell you anything: your question is vague. What did you do? (exact commands). What you expect? What you got? With such information we may help.

Comment: Can you try `python -m pip install ...`? You might use a wrong pip binary. To list your packages, `python -m pip list`

Comment: "Did you activate the virtualenv before installing the packages?": yes I did

Comment: Check if you get the right pip using `which pip` too

Comment: "Can you try python -m pip install ...? You might use a wrong pip binary. To list your packages, python -m pip list": I just tried, still saying it installed but not installing

Comment: "As you may imagine, probably they..." Ill edit my post to provide more detail

Comment: What do you mean with "but not installing"? Do you see the package using `python -m pip list`?

Comment: if i do python -m pip install numpy while in my activated directory it will do all the process of installation but then when I do python -m pip list it is not there, if I check the folder manually it is still not there

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps in order -

In your current working directory :

```sh
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
(venv) pip3 install library_name
```

To check if libraries were properly installed or not :

```sh
(venv) pip3 freeze
```

and check if your installed libraries is displayed on the terminal screen or not.

To deactivate the virtual environment :

```sh
(venv) deactivate
```

Answer (score -1):

This is due to permission issues

Run this command to change permission of your virtual environment folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 venv
```

After activating your virtual environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Then try to install Django by either Python3 or Python2

```
pip3 install django or pip install django
```

Then check the list of installed packages by either Python3 or Python2

```
pip3 list or pip list
```

NOTE: If you run `sudo pip3 install django or pip install` in virtual environment that is not writeable by default it will be installed outside of virtual environment

If you run `pip3 install django or pip install` in virtual environment that is not writtable by default it will be installed outside of virtual environment you will get OS Persmission Error

I have used `pip3 and pip` because you can install packages by either `Python3 or Python2`, thing to remember if you created virtual environment by `Python3, use pip3 and if you created by using Python2 use pip`.

Comment: Why should anyone rewrite permissions over default ones for venv folder? Why should someone referring to python3 at all times, want to install something with python2 (therefore not compatible with python3)? Also, you cannot be sure that `pip` refers to python2 pip without checking the alias first. Finally, you never talk about activating the venv in your steps, so any command you execute will still be outside your venv. You're probably installing things in your global python installation (or one of them). Your steps are imprecise and probably not produce the desired output.